# how to Rename a tab using Javascript Key events?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Selected tab]

[image: edit field]

As you can see in the picture that if i click the selected tab "Navigation" then only the rename option is appearing (pic 2). I want to make this via key board.

**JavaScript code:**

```
_makeEditable: function() {
            var instance = this;

            if (instance._isModifiable) {
                var currentItem = instance._navBlock.find('li.selected');
                var currentLink = currentItem.find('a');
                var currentSpan = currentLink.find('span');

                currentLink.click(
                    function(event) {
                        if (event.shiftKey) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                );
```

Comment: You'd need JS for that kind of behavior

Comment: Can you please clarify the question (a lot)?

Comment: In the first pic u can see that Navigation tab is selected and the page you are viewing is navigation that contains the navigation portlet. Now suppose u want to rename the tab name , then u have to click on it and it will appear like the 2nd pic, where we can rename it and save it. I want to do it via key board, like we press f2 key for rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

prototype.js:

```
document.observe('keydown', mainWindowKeyDown);
```

jquery (not sure about this, I don't use jquery often):

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).keydown(mainWindowKeyDown);
});
```

The keydown handler could be something like:

```
/*  
Called when hitting any key.
*/
function mainWindowKeyDown(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 113) // when F2 is pressed
        triggerTabRename();        
    //else if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 90) // when ctrl + 'z' pressed
    //    doSomethingWhenCtrlZWasPressed(e);
    //else if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 88) // when ctrl + 'x' pressed
    //    doSomethingWhenCtrlXWasPressed(e);
}
```

[Here](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/What-is-the-list-of-KeyCodes-for-JavaScript-KeyDown-KeyPress-and-KeyUp-events.aspx) you can find a list of keycodes.